# Django: filter() or get()

Tags: python, django

Is the way I write `discount_code.first().is_active()` the right way, or is it preferable to work with `.get` as (discount) code is a code unique field per event? Different events can have the code.

```
def clean_code(self):
        input_code = self.cleaned_data['code']

        # Check if discount code exists
        discount_code = self.event.discounts.filter(code=input_code)
        discount_code_exists = discount_code.exists()
        if not discount_code_exists:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("The discount code couldn't be found."),
                                        code='code_exists')
        else:
            if not discount_code.first().is_active():
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("This discount code is not available\
                                               anymore."),
                                            code='code_not_active')
        return input_code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save a query here. The return value of `.first()` on the queryset has all the info you need for your validation:

```
def clean_code(self):
    input_code = self.cleaned_data['code']

    # this is None if it doesn't exist
    discount_code = self.event.discounts.filter(code=input_code).first()

    if not discount_code:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("The discount code couldn't be found."),
                                    code='code_exists')
    if not discount_code.is_active():
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("This discount code is not available anymore."),
                                    code='code_not_active')
    return input_code
```

Using `exists()` is only beneficial if you do not need to process the queryset any further (which you do in the `is_active` check). And even then, you need large amounts of data to see real performance gains.

Comment: As the statement says, "Explicit is better than implicit". To me, seeing `filter` means "it can return multiple values", and `get` means "it should return one value". So I find strange doing `filter().first()` instead of `get`.

Comment: @mistiru I don't disagree, given the uniqueness of `code`. Your solution is principled and perfectly valid. I would, however, consider my approach a bit more readable and tidy as all invalid cases are handled and detected in the same way (`if`).

Answer (score 1):

I would have written the code this way:

```python
def clean_code(self):
    input_code = self.cleaned_data['code']

    try:
        discount_code = self.event.discounts.get(code=input_code)
    except Discount.DoesNotExist:  # suppose your model is named Discount
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("The discount code couldn't be found."),
                                    code='code_exists')

    if not discount_code.is_active():
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("This discount code is not available anymore."),
                                    code='code_not_active')

    return input_code
```